# Pass inherited Stream as WCF parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream

**Synopsis**:

A WCF service can accept a `Stream` as a parameter. How can I get it to accept a class **inheriting** from `Stream`?

**Long version**:

I can pass a class which has a `Stream` property, as a parameter to a WCF service by decorating the class with:

```
[MessageContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Class1))]
etc.
```

I'm now trying to do something similar with a class **inheriting** from Stream, but try as I may - it doesn't work. Mainly, I've tried decorating it with:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyStream))]
```

But I get an **error**:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:mystream. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.IO.MemoryStream' with data contract name
>   'MemoryStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is
>   not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types
>   not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by
>   **using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute** or by adding them to the list
>   of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

But I *am* using `KnownTypeAttribute`! So what's happening here, and how do I solve it? (I've already tried using `[MessageContract]` and some other options.)

Comment: When your using a DataContract, don't you need DataMembers defining the elements you're sending. Basically the same with MessageContracts - don't you need MessageHeader and MessageBody?

Comment: @Brian Yes. That's what the `etc.` in the first code meant. (I was trying to be succinct.) Thanks.

Comment: I stream over WCF, but I use basicHTTPBinding and a DataContract with one DataMember for text (all my header crap) and another for bytes, which effectively gets converted to base64 when sent over the wire. But that doesn't really answer the question.